# jQuery.ajax Why not access the item from php json_encode?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I do not understand because when the data were entered into the login are correct and I make this comparison **response.success == "success"** nothing happens, I check with firebug and the result is this:

**Response**

```
[{"ncontrol":"09680040","nombre":"Edgardo","apellidop":"Ramirez","apellidom":"Leon","tUser":"Admin","status":"success"}]
```

jQuery.ajax script to send data

```
    // jQuery.ajax script to send json data to php script

    var action = $("#formLogin").attr('action');
    var login_data = {
        ncontrol: $("#ncontrolLogin").val(),
        password: $("#passwdLogin").val(),
        is_ajax: 1
    };  

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: action,
        data: login_data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response)
        {   
            **if(response.status == "success")** {
                $("#status_msg").html("(+) Correct Login");

            }
            else {
                $("#status_msg").html("(X) Error Login!");
            }
        }
    }); 
    return false;
```

And is PHP Script for processing variables from jQuery.ajax

```
$ncontrolForm = $_REQUEST['ncontrol'];
$passForm = $_REQUEST['password'];
$jsonResult = array();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE ncontrol = '$ncontrolForm' AND cve_user = SHA('$passForm')";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die (mysqli_error());
    $num_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if( $num_row >= 1 ) {       

        $_SESSION['n_control'] = $row['ncontrol'];
        $_SESSION['t_user'] = $row['tUser'];

        $jsonResult[] = array (
            'ncontrol' => $row['ncontrol'],
            'nombre' => $row['nombre'],
            'apellidop' => $row['apellidop'],
            'apellidom' => $row['apellidom'],               
            'tUser' => $row['tUser'],
            'status' => 'success',

        );
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($jsonResult);

    }
```

Comment: You are send an array, not a object. If you want use response.success you need return "{"ncontrol":"09680040","nombre":"Edgardo","apellidop":"Ramirez","apellidom":"Leon","tUser":"Admin","status":"success"}", change "$jsonResult[] = array" by "$jsonResult = array".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an array, so do it this way:

```
if(response[0].status == "success") {
```

The object is the first item in the array.

EDIT:

Looking more closely at your PHP, it looks like you might be intending to loop through several rows in your query response and add them to your `$jsonResult`. Am I seeing it right?

Comment: @SoldierCorp, What I meant was: Do you expect to get more than one record from your SQL query? If so, you should loop through and collect all of the returned records. That will also require a loop in the ajax `success` function to test each record. Or, better yet, you could include ` AND status = "success"` in your SQL.

Comment: Well, I think I still do not understand but when I do the query if I need more information such as name and type of user and that is what my code and executes it well, or to better understand, you could put some code to see I'm wrong or you could apply optimization, thanks!

Comment: What I'm asking is: What if `$num_row` is more than 1? Don't you want to return all of the rows selected? Right now, you're only returning the first row. Your JSON string will only contain data for the first row.

Comment: ahh ok, now I understand what you say, in response, I just want to get a row of records as the control number of a student is unique and does not exist in any other student, then no problem as it will always be 1